# How to prepare for selenium interview?

Tags: selenium

For selenium with java automation testing, which topic I have to concentrate more to crack an interview. Anyone can suggest me?

Comment: Practice test automation using Selenium. Don't prepare for interview, prepare for life and you will be ready for interview automatically!

Comment: I interviewed people who knew what CSS locator means but couldn't implement a simple loop with if/when statement inside. Learn programming, not only Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a crash course?

If I was to interview a candidate, I would ask the following questions:

- What is Selenium?
- Why do we use Selenium?

If you have answered the questions above successfully, I would continue to ask:

- What are the most common problems you have encountered in test case development using Selenium?
- What are the most common methods to locate an element?
- Is there anything that x-path can do but CSS selector can not?
- Give me a few examples on how to locate a web element.

I might even provide you with a HTML web page, asking you how to locate a certain element using a given method, e.g. x-path, CSS selector

- What are the most common exceptions you have encountered?
- What if an element cannot be located no matter how you have tried? What might the reasons be?
- Tell me about page object model.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hay thanks to all for quick replay. But which java portion I have  to concentrate

Comment: @swagatika, how to build a page object model with Java and Java syntax in locating elements.

Comment: I am  asking like java which portion like Oop concept as I know apart from that any other portion

Comment: You should know good deal about methods, classes, inheritance, file operations, in short you should be well versed with core Java.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on candidate if he/she is a fresher or experienced. If you are experienced candidate they should ask what are the frameworks you used till now and etc., Maximum of 5% to 10% of java will be used in selenium. But interviewer will ask more questions on java only. So we need to prepare more on core java basic concepts.

Here are some Java topics that you need to know to crack an interview.

1.OOP’s concept – Class, Objects Polymorphism, Inheritance and Encapsulation

2.Java Programming essentials- Object Instances, method overloading/overriding concepts and packages

3.Control Statements – While, do-While, Switch, If statements – This will help us in writing the scripts for multiple scenario statements and decision making scenarios.

4.Looping statements – This will help us in scenarios like, iterating through a large table to find a record that you want and Running the same test for multiple number of times.

5.Arrays Concepts – This will help us in having some set of datas of same type in a static way.

6.Threads and MultiThreading Concepts – This will help us in making run our scripts in different threads that will help us in achieving better performance.

7.Java Collections Framework – ArrayLists and HashMaps – This will help us in maintaining a collection of data’s. Particularly useful for scenarios where you need to compare the data from Web app UI with the DB. [OR] From UI to another UI

8.File Streams – This will be helpful in externalization of data through CSV, Excel or Java Properties file.

Selenium:

1.What are the limitations of selenium?

2.Can we automate captcha? How we will handle? (If your answer is NO/Yes)

3.Can bar-code be automated?

4.Can webdriver test mobile applications?

Click [Here](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/selenium-interview-questions-answers/) you can find most popularly asked questions in selenium.